# dd (data/disk dump, copy and convert) best practices for backups in local external drives

Tags: linux, freebsd, backup, dd, disk-image

As a domestic user wishing to get best value for it's money on external storage and a well encrypted and resilient backup discipline (having all time in the world).

Please, is this a good use of dd?

```
cp /Volumes/bkp/d1.img.dd.gz /Volumes/bkp/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")-d1-bkp.img.dd.gz 
sudo dd bs=16M if=/Volumes/d1 | gzip -c > /Volumes/bkp/d1-bkp.img.dd.gz
sudo dd bs=16M if=/System/Volumes/Data | gzip -c > /Volumes/bkp/Sys-Vols-Data-bkp.img.dd.gz
```

Please, should ddrescue be used over dd? Or even, rsync be used (and if so, when would dd be aplicabe?)?

Please, when using dd, what is the best way to deal with:

- Compression?
- Encryption? (better to encrypt the whole disk? and what's the best map schemes and format for desk-laptop use with external drives?)

Any other best practices to keep in mind, please?

Comment: Welcome to the Unix & Linux StackExchange, Bruno. Many "best" questions get closed as being primarily opinion-based, since what is best for one use case may not be best fors others.  Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/670216/edit) and make it more specific to the particular values or costs you want to minimize.  Do you want a method that is the most secure for your data?  Or a method that is as fast as possible? Or that uses the least disk space?  Or the least CPU-intensive?  As your question stands, too many variables exist to say that one is conclusively best.

Comment: A backup via `dd` backs up the (possibly corrupted) filesystem accurately ONLY if the filesystem isn't `mount`ed. You will only discover filesystem corruption on the restore (this has happened to me). It's better to use a backup method that traverses the filesystem. Read `man -k backup;man tar rsync`. The ONLY justification for `dd` backup I've ever encountered is "for computer security  forensic investigation". (Given disk X, connected to a crime, `dd` X to 1st gen copy disk A, `dd` A to 2nd gen copies. Investigate only 2nd gen copies.)

Comment: Thank you! Would it be then tar pipe gzip pipe rsync ? Or even tar | rsync? Would rsync be able to do its magic? There are several good options (-aulP —delete) that I can’t see functioning well in a single file, unless rsync was made with this purpose.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dd` is the worst way to create backups:

- Enormous file sizes
- Near impossible to deduplicate data
- Near impossible to create incremental backups
- Doesn't allow to compress efficiently
- If your filesystem gets corrupted, you will backup inconsistent data

In your examples above, why would you use it at all?

```
cp /Volumes/bkp/d1.img.dd.gz /Volumes/bkp/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")-d1-bkp.img.dd.gz 
sudo  gzip -c /Volumes/d1 > /Volumes/bkp/d1-bkp.img.dd.gz
sudo  gzip -c /System/Volumes/Data > /Volumes/bkp/Sys-Vols-Data-bkp.img.dd.gz
```

Many way too often use `dd` when they can use the source device directly and the latter is faster because utilities will not have to fill their buffers to start working with the data.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Why is it such a common misuse/abuse? Is it because people love to mount volumes and play around with them as a single encrypted file?

Comment: rsync with tar would NOT keep the backup in a single file… rsync would lose the delta encoding capability… https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599271/can-rsync-be-used-to-only-copy-change-within-an-archive